# ScheduledExecutorService with partial task ordering

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduler

My tasks contain some identifier. I need ScheduledExecutionService, which will execute given tasks after specified time interval (as all standard implementations do), but with one restriction: it must not start the task, until previous task with the same identifier completes (other tasks, of course, must execute concurrently).

In other words, for given ID all tasks must be executed serially.

Is there ready to use implementation in standard or 3-rd party library or easy way to implement it?

Also returned ScheduledFuture.cancel must work correctly, because scheduled task may be cancelled by the currently executed task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough idea of how I would do it. (Not tested)

```
public class Solution {

    private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1000);
    //a map of taskQueues. We queue all tasks of same ID.
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, BlockingDeque<MyTask>> mapOfTasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(1000);

    public boolean submitWithChecks(Runnable task, long ID, long interval) {


        final BlockingDeque<MyTask> queue;
        if(mapOfTasks.containsKey(ID)) queue = mapOfTasks.get(ID);
        else queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(1000);

        //At this point we have a valid queue object

        try {
            //insert the task into the queue
            queue.putLast(new MyTask(task, ID, interval));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        //If the queue was already present it will get Updated my previous queue.putLast operation
        //If the queue was not present, we put it in the map and start a new queueEater thread.
        if(!mapOfTasks.containsKey(ID)) {
            mapOfTasks.put(ID, queue);
            scheduler.submit(new QueueEater(ID)); //start a new task execution queue
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class QueueEater implements Runnable {

        //This queueEater will consume the queue with this taskID
        private final Long ID;

        private QueueEater(Long id) {
            ID = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //QueueEater will poll the mapOfTasks for the queue Object with its associated ID
            while (mapOfTasks.containsKey(ID)) {

                final BlockingDeque<MyTask> tasks = mapOfTasks.get(ID);
                if(tasks.size() == 0) {
                    mapOfTasks.remove(ID);
                    return; //if task queue empty kill this thread;
                }

                final MyTask myTask;
                try {
                    myTask = tasks.takeFirst();
                    //schedule the task with given interval
                    final Future future = scheduler.schedule(myTask.getTask(), myTask.getInterval(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    future.get(); //wait till this task gets executed before scheduling new task
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private class MyTask {

        private final Runnable task;
        private final long ID;
        private final long interval;

        public long getInterval() {
            return interval;
        }

        public long getID() {
            return ID;
        }

        public Runnable getTask() {
            return task;
        }

        private MyTask(Runnable task, long id, long interval) {
            this.task = task;
            ID = id;
            this.interval = interval;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made similar solution. https://gist.github.com/vbezhenar/cc49928995c03c1289bb here's code.